# Which quotients of surface groups are linear?

Tags: gr.group-theory, algebraic-groups

Let $S$ be a compact connected Riemann surface, and let $\pi = \pi_1(S)$ be its fundamental group. Let $\pi \to G$ be a surjective homomorphism.

> > Is $G$ linear? (That is, does $G$ admit a faithful representation $G\to \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ for some $n>0?$ )

What if the kernel of $\pi$ is finite?

I expect the answer to be negative (when $\mathrm{genus}(S) >1$), but I am not sure where to start looking.

Comment: Hyperbolic surface groups are SQ universal, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQ-universal_group, that is every countable group embeds into their quotient. Thus just take your favorite nonlinear group and embed it in a quotient of a surface group.

Comment: That's amazing. Thank you. I knew this was to much to hope for. However, if the kernel is finite, I presume the answer is positive. Or is that also false?

Comment: Surface groups are torsion free (except for the projective plane).

Comment: Dani Wise has a very sophisticated result for building linear quotients of surface (and other) groups, called the *malnormal special quotient theorem*. If you want a very refined linear quotient of a surface group, you may want to look it up.

Comment: Surface group map onto $F_2$ (clear)...